# Sorting a list of a custom type

Tags: c++, stl

I want to have a stl `list` of objects where each object contains two `int`'s.
Afterwards I want to sort the list with `stl::sort` after the value of the first `int`.
How do I tell the sort function that it's supposed to sort after the first `int`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can specify a custom sort predicate. In C++11 this is best done with a lambda:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> ipair;
std::list<ipair> thelist;

thelist.sort([](const ipair & a, const ipair & b) { return a.first < b.first; });
```

In older versions of C++ you have to write an appropriate function:

```
bool compFirst(const ipair & a, const ipair & b) { return a.first < b.first; }

thelist.sort(compFirst);
```

(Instead if `ipair` you can of course have your own data structure; just modify the comparison function accordingly to access the relevant data member.)

Finally, if this makes sense, you can also equip your custom class with an `operator<`. That allows you to use the class freely in any ordered context, but be sure to understand the consequences of that.

Comment: Hello. I'm using you "older version" sort but it keeps leaving one element unsorted: the last element on the original list does not get sorted, it always remains the last element. Do you know what might be wrong? Thanks

Comment: @MarcoCastanho: I don't think that can/should happen. Sounds like you have a bug somewhere. Feel free to post a question; make sure to create a *minimal* reproducing example.

Answer (score 3):

`std::list<T>::sort` [has a one-argument form](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/), with the first argument being the comparison function.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks. Some day I'll hunt down the person who decided that std::sort could not just be specialized for list iterators, but had to be incorporated into the class.

Comment: Don't. It doesn't make sense. List sorting is totally different and has nothing to do with iterators. The standard sort works by *swapping values*, while list sort takes advantage of the container's nature and just rehooks the element nodes. Note that list sort does *not* accept an iterator pair!

Comment: @KerrekSB: And is even likely to use a wholly different algorithm that is more suited to sequential-access containers than quicksort. Sure. Still the same from the user's POV, modulo a few differences in iterator behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
typedef std::pair<int,int>;
list<my_type> test_list;

bool my_compare (my_type a, my_type b)
{
    return a.first < b.first;
}

test_list.sort(my_compare);
```

If the type was a struct or class it would work something like this:

```
struct some_struct{
    int first;
    int second;
};

list<some_struct>  test_list;

bool my_compare (const some_struct& a,const some_struct& b)
{
    return a.first < b.first;
}

test_list.sort(my_compare);
```

Or alternatively you can define `operator <` for your struct and just call `test_list.sort()`