# C++ Own comparison in std::list

Tags: c++, containers, stdlist

I have some structure in my program and list of them.
It's something like this:

```
struct person{
    string name;
    char relation;
    string child;
}
typedef std::list < person > listP;

listP MyList;
```

I want sort this list by `person.name` using `std::list::sort()` but I don't know how to deal with it. I tried to find how to use STL custom comparisons, but now it's little to strange for me, so please explain this humanly :P

Comment: What in particular didn't you understand from the [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) reference?

Comment: What exactly isn't clear? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort

Comment: Sooo... I tried to code custom comparison and I made sth like that:
`struct {
 bool operator()(person & a, person & b)
 {
  return a.name < b.name;
 }
} customLess;
std::sort(MyList.begin(),MyList.end(),customLess);`

Comment: Don't use `std::sort` with a list. It expects random access iterators, which `std::list` doesn't provide. Use the list member function `sort`

Comment: OK, I have now sth like this, but it's still show me errors...
http://wklej.org/id/1662834/

Comment: Also, since you don't intend to modify the referenced object, pass by a const reference. Always be const correct. The standard library is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list::sort` requires a predicate function-object.

You can try:

```
std::list<person> people;

// Add some people...

people.sort([](const person &left, const person &right)
{
    return left.name < right.name;
});
```

See also:

[Sorting a list of a custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121837/sorting-a-list-of-a-custom-type)

Comment: Finally concrete answer. Thanks, it was very helpful :) BTW - nice idea with lambda expression, looks great :) I see this functions very rarely :P