# Custom comparator for C++ STL Sort error expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

Tags: c++

I need to use STL sort function with a custom comparator. If I directly used the comparator function as argument to sort, it gives error of non-static method. So I created a functor. Still it gives error: -

```
class Graph
{
private:
    struct edge
    {
        int src;
        int dest;
        int weightage;
    };
    typedef struct edge * edgePtr;

    list<edgePtr> edgeList ;

    struct compareEdgeWeightage
    {
        int src, dest, weightage;
        bool operator() (list<edgePtr>::iterator edge1ptr , list<edgePtr>::iterator edge2ptr ) const
        {
            edgePtr edge1 = *edge1ptr;
            edgePtr edge2 = *edge2ptr;
            return( (edge1->weightage) < (edge2->weightage) ) ;
        }
    }; //struct compareEdgeWeightage


public:
    Graph();
    void addEdge(int src, int dest, int weightage);
    void MST();

};// class Graph


void Graph::MST()
{
    sort( edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(),compareEdgeWeightage);
} //MST
```

I have omitted other irrelevant functions and lines just for clarity. 
Compiling it gives the error

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

Comment: Duplicate: [*sorting a list of a custom type*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121837/sorting-a-list-of-a-custom-type)

Answer (score 1):

The comparator should take the compared objects as arguments, not iterators, so:

```
bool operator() (edgePtr a, edgePtr b){...}
```

Alternatively, you can use a lambda too make your code more compact:

```
sort(edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(),
     [](edgePtr lhs, edgePtr rhs)->bool {
         return( (lhs->weightage) < (rhs->weightage) );
     });
```

Your other problem is that you are trying to pass the *type* of your comparator as the third parameter of `sort`, while you should really be passing an object, so you can either call it with

```
// note that we are creating an object of compareEdgeWeightage here
std::sort(edgeList.begin(), edgeList.end(), compareEdgeWeightage());
```

or, better yet, create a single comparator inside your class and use it to avoid creating/copying extra objects:

```
class Graph
{
    <...>
    struct compareEdgeWeightage
    {
        <...>
    }comparator;
};

void Graph::MST()
{
    std::sort( edgeList.begin(), edgeList.end(), comparator );
}
```

You also only really need the `operator()` in the comparator, so you can get rid of the extra stuff:

```
struct compareEdgeWeightage
{
    bool operator() (edgePtr edge1ptr , edgePtr edge2ptr) const
    {
        return( (edge1ptr->weightage) < (edge2ptr->weightage) ) ;
    }
};
```

And then, finally, `std::sort` requires random access iterators to work, so you will need to use the built-in `sort` of the list, which fortunately does support custom comparators:

```
void Graph::MST()
{
    edgeList.sort(comparator);
}
```

Comment: Your lambda has a typo.  Arguments are lhs/rhs, but you use edge1, edge2.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SingerOfTheFall

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `compareEdgeWeightage` is a *type* but you need to pass an *object* of that type to the [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function.

Try:

```
void Graph::MST()
{
    std::sort(edgeList.begin(), edgeList.end(), compareEdgeWeightage());
}
```

You have other problems too, for example your `std::list` containes pointers, not iterators so this is needed:

```
struct compareEdgeWeightage
{
    int src, dest, weightage;

    // compare pointers not iterators
    bool operator() (edgePtr edge1ptr , edgePtr edge2ptr) const
    {
        return edge1ptr->weightage < edge2ptr->weightage;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately though [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) doesn't work with `std::list` because it requires something like a *contiguous* container (actually a container that provides *random access iterators*) like a `std::vector`.

Comment: It actually requires a container that provides random access iterators, doesn't need to be contiguous, but yes you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of the functor class, and pass that to `std::sort`.  So the code should look like:

```
    std::sort( edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(),compareEdgeWeightage());
```

or

```
    compareEdgeWeightage cmp;
    std::sort( edgeList.begin(),edgeList.end(),cmp);
```

As noted by SingerOfTheFall, `std::sort` is going to pass `*it1, *it2` as arguments to your functor, so you need to accept the arguments by value or reference.  In general I would suggest const reference, but as `edgePtr` is just a pointer, by value is better here.

```
bool operator() (const edgePtr lhs, const edgePtr rhs) const
{
    return lhs->weightage < rhs->weightage
}
```

As an aside, you don't need `int src, dest, weightage;` in the functor.  They do nothing, and are never initialized or used.

None of the above will help though - you can't use `std::sort` with a `std::list`.  `std::sort` requires random access iterators, and `std::list` only provides bidirectional ones.  You need to use `edgeList.sort(..)`

Finally, it is impossible to tell what is causing the bash error - we need to see the full script to explain that.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Note: I have fixed the problem that edgePtrs are pointers.

Comment: Ah.  Never mind.  Somebody (almost certainly the same somebody) has downvoted *all* the answers here.

Comment: Maybe a bit harsh (removed) but `std::sort` has requirements on the iterators which make using it with `std::list` problematic.

Comment: Oooh!  *GOOD* spot.  Blimey, that's *three* problems with the OP's code!  I only actually saw the one creating the actual reported error.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @MartinBonner