# how to sort a list containing maps in it

Tags: c++

i'm trying to sort a list of maps by its second float number(in the `pair<float,float>`) like this:

`list<map<string, pair<float, float>>>`

can anyone help me with this...

i'v tried this so far:

```
void my_sort(list<map<string, pair<float, float>>> ans)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < ans.size(); i++)
    {
        for (list<map<string, pair<float, float>>>::iterator j = ans.begin(); j < ans.end; j++)
        {
            if(j->)
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me with this...

Comment: So, you want to sort by a `float` in an `std::pair`, which is a value for `std::map`, but how do you choose **_which_** pair in the map should be used for comparisons? This is a terribly convoluted data structure. You should probably rethink your design.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Please show sample input data and desired results.

Comment: " list of maps by its second float number(in the pair<float,float>)" ... strictly speaking there is no "second float number in the list", if you sort the list you are actually soring maps. And those map may(!) contain pairs of floats. It is not obvious how this comparison should take place..

Comment: I guess you going to sort the pair<float, float> inside the map as well?
Please give us an example. Let's say you have
{   {{ "a", { 1, 3 }}, {"b", {2, 6}}, {"c", {3, 4}}}, {{"A", {12,10}},{"B",{0,2}}, {"C",{3,8}}}. What do you want to see after sort?

Comment: @Tony `std::map` is always sorted by key (`std::string` in this case).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121837/sorting-a-list-of-a-custom-type

Comment: @Yksisarvinen He is trying to sort with the second value of a pair value in the map, so it has nothing to do with the sorted map. The map is sorted with the key - which is a string.

Comment: Because there is no 'second float' of a map, which makes me to think that, he is probably trying to sort all the pair in all the maps, and reform them together into a big map.

Answer (score 1):

You don't make it very clear how to compare two of your maps, but once you figure that out you can perform a custom sort using a custom less than operator, like so:

```
struct less_than_key
{
    inline bool operator() (map<string, pair<float, float>> &map1, map<string, pair<float, float>> &map2)
    {
        // Here you need to figure out what makes one map 'less than' the other
        // If if a specific key's value.second is < the same in the other map, for example.
        return map1IsLessThanMap2;
    }
};

std::sort(yourList.begin(), yourList.end(), less_than_key());
```